# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while passing multiple parameters in Onclick

Tags: jquery

Good day. I am getting the below error in Jquery during my function executes.Please help to me find out if there is any syntax issue.

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
RedirectTo(5566,1003219,00:55)

function LoadSearch(model) {           
    return '<a id="expExcel" href="#" onclick=RedirectTo(' + model.MasterContent_ID + ',' + model.MasterSlot_Id + ',' + model.MasterSlot_Duration + ')><img alt="Search & Schedule" title="Search & Schedule" src="../Content/images/SearchSlotSelect.png" height="15" width="15">';
}
```

Regards,
Snehasish

Comment: function LoadSearch(model) {         
            return '<a id="expExcel" href="#" onclick=RedirectTo(' + model.MasterContent_ID + ',' + model.MasterSlot_Id + ',' + model.MasterSlot_Duration + ')><img alt="Search & Schedule" title="Search & Schedule" src="../Content/images/SearchSlotSelect.png" height="15" width="15">';

        }

Comment: probably RedirectTo(5566,1003219,00:55) may be the cause of problem, change it to RedirectTo(5566,1003219,"00:55")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cause of the problem is with the last parameter in this function call `RedirectTo(5566,1003219,00:55)`.

Because it is not considered as a numeric value since it has `:` in it. So you need to treat it as string.

Wrap the `00:55` with quotes like this,

```
RedirectTo(5566,1003219,"00:55")
```

**Edit**

```
return '<a id="expExcel" href="#" onclick=RedirectTo(' + model.MasterContent_ID + ',' + model.MasterSlot_Id + ',' + '"' + model.MasterSlot_Duration + '"' + ')><img alt="Search & Schedule" title="Search & Schedule" src="../Content/images/SearchSlotSelect.png" height="15" width="15">';
```

Comment: it's giving syntax error if i am trying to keep in " + model.MasterSlot_Duration +".Please suggest

Comment: use the return statement, which I have used in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would sugges you to use an object instead:

```
function LoadSearch(model) { 
    var obj = {mcid:model.MasterContent_ID, msid:model.MasterSlot_Id, msd:model.MasterSlot_Duration};          
    return '<a id="expExcel" href="#" onclick=RedirectTo('+ obj + ')><img alt="Search & Schedule" title="Search & Schedule" src="../Content/images/SearchSlotSelect.png" height="15" width="15">';
}
```

Now in the `RedirectTo(obj)` function you can access the values like:

```js
function RedirectTo(obj) {
  console.log(obj.mcid, obj.msid, obj.msd);
}
RedirectTo({
  mcid: 5566,
  msid: 1003219,
  msd: "00:55"
})
```